# How do I make a call OK HttpRequest post from an isolated class using async?

Tags: java, android, class, okhttp

I was using this in another place as async but I wanted to refactor to make it reusable, how can I reorganize the code in order to work as a consumable class?. It doesn't work if it's not async and the ip of the backend is well defined so it's not that. Any ideas?

```
public class HTTPRequestManager {

    public static JSONArray fetchData(){


        return null;

    }

    public static String postData(Context context, String url, String JSONData)  {




            return null;
    }

   /* @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {
            //1.create client Object
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            //2.Define request being sent to server
            RequestBody postData = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), JSONData);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(context.getResources().getString(R.string.backend_base_url) + url)
                    .post(postData)
                    .build();

            //3.Transport the request and wait for response to process next

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String resultData = response.body().string();

            if (resultData.equals("OK")) {

            } else  {
                //post failed
                return "FAILED";


            }


            return resultData;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("API_CONNECTION_ERROR", "Couldn't connect to the API");
            return "API_CONNECTION_ERROR";
        }

    }*/


}
```

I used to have this annonymous class embeeded in another class and it works(it's a get request) but the problem is that it's not reusable in that way:

```
public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
            Integer result = 0;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
            try {
                url = new URL (getResources().getString(R.string.backend_base_url) +
                        "api/flrcks/user/id/0/latitude/3000/longitude/300/within/9999999999999999999999999");
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                // 200 represents HTTP OK
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                    }
                    parseResult(response.toString());
                    result = 1; // Successful
                } else {
                    result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return result; //"Failed to fetch data!";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // Download complete. Let us update UI
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (result == 1) {
                adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter_Nearby(getActivity(), feedsList);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                checkAdapterIsEmpty();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to fetch data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                t.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        private void parseResult(String result) {
            try {
                JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONArray posts = response.getJSONArray("rows");
                feedsList = new ArrayList<>();

                JSONArray members;
                for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                    memberList = new ArrayList<>();
                    final JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
                    members=post.getJSONArray("members");
                    final FeedItem item = new FeedItem();


                //for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                    //JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
                    //FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                    item.setId(post.optString("id"));
                    item.setTitle(post.optString("name"));
                    item.setDescription(post.optString("description"));
                    item.setPrivacy(post.optString("privacy_mode_description"));
                    item.setInitial_date(post.optString("initial_date"));
                    item.setThumbnail(post.optString("thumbnail"));
                    item.setColor_hex(post.optString("color_hex"));
                    item.setTag(post.optString("tag"));
                    item.setDistance(post.optInt("st_distance"));


                    //item.setThumbnail(post.optString("thumbnail"));

                    for(int k=0; k <members.length();k++)
                    {
                        MemberItem memberItem = new MemberItem();
                        JSONObject member = members.optJSONObject(k);
                        memberItem.setName(member.optString("name"));
                        memberItem.setUsername(member.optString("username"));
                        memberItem.setProfile_pic(member.optString("profile_pic"));
                        memberItem.setIs_moderator(member.optBoolean("is_moderator"));
                        memberItem.setFacebookId(member.optString("facebook_id"));



                        memberList.add(memberItem);
                    }
                    item.setMemberList(memberList);
                    feedsList.add(item);
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

What changes do I need to make to put it in an isolated file to be consumed by the whole app like for example in a file called OkHTTPRequests.class???

Answer (score 0):

**Create an interface**

```
public interface OnWebResponseListener {
    void onWebResponse(CommonUtilities.services service, String result);
}
```

create a **public enum** for identifying service. in my case i created a **CommonUtilities** java where i declared

```
 public enum services {
        LOGIN
    }
```

Your Common File

```
public class CallAddr extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    CommonUtilities.services service;
    OnWebResponseListener onWebResponseListener;
    String url;
    FormBody.Builder body;
    Request request;
    OkHttpClient client;
    final static String TAG = "CallAddr";

    public CallAddr(Map<String, String> data, CommonUtilities.services service, OnWebResponseListener onWebResponseListener, String url) {
        this.service = service;
        this.onWebResponseListener = onWebResponseListener;
        this.url = url;
        body = new FormBody.Builder();
        for (String key : data.keySet()) {
            body.add(key, data.get(key));
        }
        client = new OkHttpClient();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String result = "";
        request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(body.build()).build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            result = response.body().string();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (onWebResponseListener != null) {
            onWebResponseListener.onWebResponse(service, s);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to create another service, just a regular class where to call the api async....does this have to be a service mandatory???isn't there an easier solution? I don't understand the enum either...

Comment: We aren't creating any other service  on this.  Enum is just like a series.  Think about it as you have made three api calls using a common class now you will get three responses asynchronously, you don't know which response is against which call in this situation you need to identify or label the response there enum comes handy.  Just goodle about enum

Comment: what is not clear to me is a case where you have more than one call , where areyou checking for that enum to see which call is??